# Pushing an iterated elements in an array into an empty array not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array that needs to loop over and get the elements into another empty Array based on some function parameters. But presently, I did not know why my code is doing something else.

```js
// 

let cart = [];


 let quantity = []; 


const prices = [ [2, 20], [7, 50], [12, 100], [17, 40], [22, 32], [27, 25 ] ];

function addItemToCart(itemCode) {
  const newItems = prices.map(price => price[0])
for(const i of newItems){
  if(itemCode === i){
    cart.push(itemCode)
  }else {
    throw 'item code not recognized'
  }
}



} 
// THIS IS FOR  TESTING ONLY.

try{
  addItemToCart(7);
  addItemToCart(7);
  addItemToCart(17);
  addItemToCart(22);
  console.log(addItemToCart(172)); // This should print 'item code not recognized'
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(cart.length) // This should print 3
 console.log(quantity[0]) // This should print 2
```

Comment: Hi, your code has some problems. First of all, why you are throwing in the middle of iteration? the loop you wrote says: "if the first item code was matched with `itemCode` push it, either, throw an error and return from function, and don't continue the iteration! So the whole else part is unnecessary. Second, what is the `quantity` variable used for? You didn't changed it anywhere and you expect it's value to be 2.

Comment: I'm throwing that error when an invalid code is supplied. I was still going to write the logic for the quantity array after pushing it to the cart array first. My cart array is supposed to be cart = [7, 7, 17, 22] while my quantity = [2, 1, 1] where quantity[0] = 2 is coming from @meshkati

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this, I think a much more reasonable and easy to manage data structure would be an *object* indexed by item ID, which holds an object containing the item ID, price, and quantity. For example, from the `[2, 20]` array item, you would create the following key-value pair:

```
2: {
  itemCode: 2,
  price: 20,
  quantity: 0
}
```

Then, when iterating, just increment the `.quantity` property on the object if it exists:

```js
const prices = [
  [2, 20],
  [7, 50],
  [12, 100],
  [17, 40],
  [22, 32],
  [27, 25]
];
const cartByItemCode = Object.fromEntries(
  prices.map(([itemCode, price]) => ([
    itemCode, // key of object,
    { quantity: 0, price, itemCode }
  ]))
);
function addItemToCart(itemCode) {
  if (!cartByItemCode[itemCode]) {
    throw 'item code not recognized: ' + itemCode;
  }
  cartByItemCode[itemCode].quantity++;
}

// THIS IS FOR  TESTING ONLY
try {
  addItemToCart(7);
  addItemToCart(7);
  addItemToCart(17);
  addItemToCart(22);
  console.log(addItemToCart(172)); // This should print 'item code not recognized'
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

const nonEmptyCartItems = Object.values(cartByItemCode).filter(({ quantity }) => quantity);
console.log(nonEmptyCartItems.length) // This should print 3
console.log(nonEmptyCartItems[0].quantity) // This should print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that during your iteration over all elements, you throw an exception for all elements that are not the target.

If `ItemCode` is 7, and we iterate over `newItems`, the first element we encounter is 2. Since `2 !== 7`, we don't enter the if, meaning we enter the else, meaning we throw an error.

You want to only throw the exception if *none* of the elements match, for which you have 2 options:

1. `newItems.indexOf(ItemCode) === -1` -> this tells you ItemCode is not in newItems, so you can throw the exception. Use this *instead of* the forloop.
2. First check all list items, then the condition. Something like this:

`let isvalid = false; for (const i of newitems) {isvalid = isvalid | i == itemcode}`

If `isvalid` is false, throw the exception.

Comment: Thank you @Cesar van der Poel

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see what you are attempting to do except for `quantity` which is not clear how it should be set.

This adds items from the price list it finds and produces a list of "errors" with why it was not included, not the most efficient but does give you insight perhaps on how to work with your arrays and function.

```js
let cart = [];
let quantity = [];

const prices = [
  [2, 20],
  [7, 50],
  [12, 100],
  [17, 40],
  [22, 32],
  [27, 25]
];
// move out since it is always the same
const newItems = prices.map(price => price[0]);

let errors = [];

function addItemToCart(itemCode) {
  if (cart.includes(itemCode)) {
    errors.push({
      "itemCode": itemCode,
      "eror": "Already in cart"
    });
    return
  }
  if (!newItems.includes(itemCode)) {
    errors.push({
      "itemCode": itemCode,
      "eror": "Not in price list"
    });
    return
  }
  newItems.filter(item => item == itemCode && !cart.includes(item)).forEach(item => cart.push(item));
}
// THIS IS FOR  TESTING ONLY.

//try {
addItemToCart(7);
addItemToCart(7);
addItemToCart(17);
addItemToCart(22);
addItemToCart(172); // This should print 'item code not recognized'
//} catch (e) {
//  console.log(e);
//}

console.log("cart:", cart, "cart count:", cart.length) // This should print 3
console.log("Errors:", errors);
console.log(quantity.length, quantity[0]) // This should print 2???
```